# Roblox RobaseService

Tags: lua, roblox

I try to implement the RobaseService. But I have some issues with the RobaseService:GetRobase.

I get the error "ServerScriptService.RobaseService:31: attempt to index nil with 'AuthKey'". Which is this line of code:

```
if self.AuthKey==nil or self.AuthKey=="" then
```

I use the standard setup of code and have only added my url and token from Firebase. I can see in the RobaseService.new function that the url and token are correct, but when RobaseService:GetRobase() is called it says that 'self' is nil. Which does not make any sense since the RobaseService have already been initialized.

This is my RobaseService:

```
local Robase = require(script.Robase)
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")

local RobaseService = { }
RobaseService.BaseUrl = nil
RobaseService.AuthKey = nil
RobaseService.__index = RobaseService

local function fixTrailingSlashes(url)
    local foundTrailingSlashes = url:match("/+$")
    url = foundTrailingSlashes and url:sub(1, url:len()-#foundTrailingSlashes) or url

    return url
end

function RobaseService.new(baseUrl, token)
    if baseUrl == nil then
        error("Bad Argument 1 baseUrl expected, got nil")
    elseif token==nil then
        error("Bad Argument 2 token expected, got nil")
    end

    local self = setmetatable({}, RobaseService)
    self.BaseUrl = fixTrailingSlashes(baseUrl)
    self.AuthKey = ".json?auth="..token
    return self
end

function RobaseService:GetRobase(name, scope)
    if self.AuthKey==nil or self.AuthKey=="" then
        error("You must instantiate RobaseService with an AuthKey to use the RobaseService API")
    elseif self.BaseUrl==nil or self.BaseUrl=="" then
        error("You must instantiate RobaseService with a BaseUrl to use the RobaseService API")
    end

    name = name and HttpService:UrlEncode(name) or ""
    scope = scope and HttpService:UrlEncode(scope) or ""
    
    local formatted = string.format("%s/%s/%s", self.BaseUrl, scope, name)
    --local formattedUrl = self.BaseUrl .. scope .. "/" .. name
    return Robase.new(formatted, self)
end

return RobaseService
```

And this is where I use the RobaseService:

```
local robaseModule = require(game:GetService("ServerScriptService").RobaseService)
local secretStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Secret")

local collectionItems = {}
local defaultSettings = {
    item1 = {ID = "SomeDude", Price = 1000, NumSold = 0, NumForSale = 999999, Level = 1, DateAdded = {Year = 2022, Month = 5, Day = 5, Hour = 11, Minute = 0, Second = 0}}
}

local RobaseService = robaseModule.new(
    secretStore:GetAsync("URL"),
    secretStore:GetAsync("AUTH")
)

local defaultRobase = RobaseService.GetRobase()

local success, serverSettings = defaultRobase:GetAsync("serverSettings")

local function applySettings()
    if serverSettings then
        print("serverSettings: ", serverSettings)
        collectionItems = serverSettings
    end
end


local function initializeSettings()
    if not serverSettings then
        warn("serverSettings finnes ikke... da har vi ikke kontakt med firebase")
        defaultRobase:SetAsync("serverSettings", defaultSettings, "PUT")
        task.wait(3)
        success, serverSettings = defaultRobase:GetAsync("serverSettings")
    end
    
    applySettings()
end


local function keepUpdating()
    --når jeg tester så bare loop på feks 10 sekunder
    --i prod så kan denne settes til feks hver time 60*60
    while task.wait(10) do
        print("oppdaterer")
        success, serverSettings = defaultRobase:GetAsync("serverSettings")
        if success then
            applySettings()
        else
            warn("ingen kontakt med Firebase. Får da ikke ut items for salg")
        end
    end
end


initializeSettings()
keepUpdating()
```

My url and token have been stored in a datastore and works fine. Anyone know why this would not work and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with how you've coded the service, but how you've called it.

You defined the function as `RobaseService:GetRobase()` but you've called it with `RobaseService.GetRobase()`. Notice the difference between calling the function with a colon versus a period.

In lua, defining the function with a colon is equivalent to defining the function like this : `function RobaseService.GetRobase(self)`. And calling a function with a colon is semantic sugar for passing the object itself as the `self` to the function as the first argument.  But because `self` is effectively an argument to the function, if you don't pass it in, it will be `nil` when your function tried to access it.

So to fix your issue, just swap the period to a colon at the call-site:

```lua
local defaultRobase = RobaseService:GetRobase()
```

Comment: This is a long explanation to say you have a typo.

Comment: Omg, I'm such a noob. Thanks very much Kylaaa. Too bad the error wasn't more specific, but at least I will probably never do this mistake again ;)